# The launchpad button does not appear in the dock?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, launchpad

Just bought a new Macbook Pro with lion, but the launchpad button is not in the dock and I can't find it anywhere on the computer. I thought it may be gone because when I started the computer I used a firewire cable to put all the information from my old Macbook into the Macbook pro, and so all the settings from the Macbook were transferred. Could this have deleted the launchpad button? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

The launchpad button is an normal application.  You should expect to find it in the /Applications folder.  If it is there, you can drag a copy to the dock.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can always access Launchpad by pinching three fingers and your thumb. This is shown in the Trackpad section of System Preferences, under "More Gestures".

Comment: No you can't. F4 takes you to Dashboard.

Comment: @tylermwashburn - I didn't realize the Pros still had Dashboard as an F-key. My mistake - it must just be the Airs that have that shortcut.